# How can i send random commands to redis?

Tags: redis, booksleeve

I am using redis via booksleeve on c#/.NET

Lets say i want to send an unimplemented command like `SCRIPT FLUSH` or `EVAL`. How do i do so with booksleeve? Also i'm not sure if echo is implemented so using that as an example would be cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flush is there - try under .Server (from memory - not near a PC). For the others - there is no "run custom command" API, but I have contributions in my inbox (waiting to be merged) that add these. They might even be attachments in the issue list (I honestly can't remember). Or wait a few days.

Comment: Actually `flush script` is for the new 2.6 lua scripting support (which i have no interest in). It removes all scripts in redis. BTW what version is booksleeve written for? 2.4 allows multiple values to be pushed with a single list command http://redis.io/commands/rpush is that implement ATM?. +1 bc... well i should just anyways automatically. You helped me plenty

Comment: @acidzombie24 sorry, my bad: I was thinking of flushdb/all. Re which version: in many cases, it chooses different strategies depending on the version it *detects*. Is there a feature I should be exploiting more here? (varadic args maybe?)

Comment: i'm not sure. I really only just read all the commands and misc documentation in the last 2 days along with playing around with the server/sending commands. I just looked at booksleeve (1.1.0.8) and i believe `Lists.AddLast` is `rpush`? I see it only allows one command at a time. If you can't advantage of 2.4 multiple push efficiencies i'd be pretty happy. It appears you can push an array of strings or bytes in `Sets.Add`. But you cant in `Lists.AddLast` so i'm not sure if you're taking advantage in that case or not (probably not?)

Comment: @acidzombie24 of course, since it is pipelined *anyway*, that advantage might not be as big as you think... it can probably be added though. DON'T assume that 7 ops costs 7 times as much as 1 op, though - because of the pipeline that is nowhere near accurate. Difference might actually be almost undetectable.